# Automatic sign-in via Google ID in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, single-sign-on, chrome-for-android

I don't know the full details of this, but I believe Google's own web properties can perform single sign on within Chrome, using the Android user's ID and with the user's permission.

Is this functionality available to third-party web apps running in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an authentication token using AccountManager. If you get the right token for the service, and add the proper headers, you should be able to achieve something similar.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant native Android apps. It's more of a Google Chrome question then. They must have same API to the platform's AccountManager within Chrome, not sure if it is exposed to third party apps or only internal